# K-theory of the Grassmannians

Tags: differential-geometry, grassmannian, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

For complex projective space its [K-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space#K-theory) is $\mathbb{Z}[H]/\langle H-1\rangle^{n-1}$. How does this generalise to the Grassmannian case?

Comment: If you are interested in infinite grassmannians, i.e. $BU(n)$, then I think Atiyah–Hirzebruch spectral sequence can yield the result, but I'm not sure...
Relevant links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space_for_U(n) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Hirzebruch_spectral_sequence

Comment: Maybe it should be noted that the K-theory of $CP^\infty$ is indeed easily computed by Atiyah Hirzebruch.